# What is the easiest way to change the colormap in Matlab plots with many lines

Tags: matlab, plot, colors

Let us take as an example this piece of code I wrote to simulate an Arithmetic Brownian Motion:

```
%% Simulate an arithmetic Brownian motion
% $$ dX(t) = mu*dt + sigma*dW(t) $$

% Define parameters and time grid
npaths = 500; % number of paths (trajectories)
T = 1; % time horizon
nsteps = 150; % number of time steps
dt = T/nsteps; % time step size
t = 0:dt:T; % observation times
mu = 0.2; sigma = 0.3; % model parameters

% Compute the increments 
dX = mu*dt + sigma*sqrt(dt)*randn(nsteps,npaths);

% Accumulate the increments: compute the ABM
X = [zeros(1,npaths); cumsum(dX)]; % sets first row as zero

% Plot 20 sample trajectories
figure(1);
plot(t,X(:,1:20)); % just select 20 trajectory for clarity's sake
```

Here I plotted 20 trajectories but I would like to find a way to change the colormap for any number of trajectory I choose. I would like brighter colours. I have this issue everytime I plot any stochastic process simulation, so I'm looking for something general I can use every time and possibly simple. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: For generating an arbitrary number of maximally perceptually distinct colors (if that is of concern?) you might want to take a look at [this Matlab central submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29702-generate-maximally-perceptually-distinct-colors). For controlling the order in which colors are displayed, take a look at the [`ColorOrder`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#prop_ColorOrder) property.

Comment: You can use the `Color` option within `plot` command, and use some tool for generating a colormap such as http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/08/15/colors-for-your-multi-line-plots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used @mikkola suggestion, the function `distinguishable_colors`.

```
% Plot 20 sample trajectories
c = distinguishable_colors(20);
a = axes; hold(a,'on');
set(a,'ColorOrder',c);  
%  
plot(t,X(:,1:20));
```

It of course works with different numbers of trajectories too.